# how to grab the first nonwhite char in cin

Tags: c++, cin

Okay, quick question.

In c++, I want to ignore whitespaces so I know I need to use cin and probably not cin.get
because a 'space' is a char.

However, I also want to to only get the first non-whitespace char and ignore the other characters if a user types in more than one. If the rest of the chars are not ignored, then the input will impact my other cin later on in the program

So I'm guessing I should use cin.ignore( ), but I also realized that I can't just add an 
argument of 1000, because the user then has to type in 1000 chars (At least when I was testing). So how do I get only the first non-whitespace char?

Answer (score 3):

The first non-whitespace character (assuming the input stream is not empty) can be obtained by clearing the leading whitespace, and then consuming the next character:

```
char firstChar = (is >> std::ws).get();
```

For clearing the rest of the input stream, you can `ignore()` all remaining characters until the next newline, something like:

```
is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

`operator<<`, as a [Formatted Input Function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/FormattedInputFunction), will discard leading whitespace characters, so you can do this:

```
char c;
cin >> c;
```

Getting rid of the rest can be done with [std::istream::ignore](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore):

```
// Ignore everything or up to the first new line character,
// whichever comes first
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```